# Using GATHER to gather user's names in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

Hi is it possible to gather users name using the gather verb?
I'm getting an application error, where can i read it's details?
Can i use any "hint" to improve gathering names?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

You can set the [input attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input) on <Gather> to speech and then use the [hints attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#hints) to provide Gather with a set of words or phrases that can make its speech to text conversion more accurate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- page located at http://example.com/simple_gather.xml -->
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech" action="/completed" hints="number, numbers, more number facts, more numbers facts">
        <Say>Welcome to Twilio, please tell us why you're calling</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's constantly mistaking saying "a" with "hey" is there a way to exlude words using the hints?